# Open external console from Netbeans using Java

Tags: java, netbeans, console

Is it possible to open an external console window when executing your Java program from Netbeans, instead of the standard inner console/output window inside of Netbeans? I have searched through the project configuration and Netbeans preferences without finding any useful option.

I know that while using C/C++ it is possible to choose from the config what console to use (inner/outer), but I'm affraid it's not possible with Java.

Does anyone have some insight into the Java matter?

Thanks!

Comment: No one has the answer... weird thing.